# Updating UI using dispatcher.beginInvoke

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8, async-await, begininvoke

So, I am reading a message through the mobile Bluetooth and I am trying to update the UI with the data I received.

Calling another method, the 'update' method as following

```
try
{
   await update();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     Debug.WriteLine("Exception has been called");
     Debug.WriteLine("Type| " + e.GetType());
     Debug.WriteLine("Inner Exception| " + e.InnerException);
     Debug.WriteLine("Message| " + e.Message);
}

and the update method goes as followes

public async Task<String> update()
{
    string[] sMsg = msg.Split(new Char[]{'\n'});

    string[] finalmsg = sMsg[0].Split(new Char[]{':'});

    if ((finalmsg.Length != 8 && sMsg[0] == msg) || sMsg.Length < 2)
    { // not finished reading 
        //Debug.WriteLine("\n\n--skip as the size is : " + finalmsg.Length);
        return null;
    }

    msg = msg.Substring(sMsg[0].Length+2,msg.Length-(sMsg[0].Length+2));
    if (finalmsg.Length >= 8){

        System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(
            new System.Threading.ThreadStart(
                   delegate()
                   {
                     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
                     {
                        string[] fm = finalmsg;
                        RX.Text = finalmsg[0];
                        RY.Text = finalmsg[1];
                        LX.Text = finalmsg[2];
                        LY.Text = finalmsg[3];
                        RF1.Text = finalmsg[4];
                        RF2.Text = finalmsg[5];
                        LF1.Text = finalmsg[6];
                        LF2.Text = finalmsg[7];
                     });
                  }
            ));

        thread.Start();

        if(!thread.IsAlive)
            thread.Abort();
        }

    return finalmsg[0];
    }            
}
```

So the problem I am facing now is that, updating the UI in the body of Dispatcher.BeginInvoke works for 20 seconds and then an exception fires as following

```
exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation
```

The exception is fired in the App.xaml, Application_UnhandledException method
That means the exception is not handled in the code, and I was not able to catch even with try clause.

What I am thinking now is I am doing a mistake because I don't really understand how dispatcher.beginInvoke

So could you please advice of what may went wrong here ?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
To elaborate more this is the stack trace of the exception I got

Stack Trace:

```
  at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
  at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
  at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
  at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)
  at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
  at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
  at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam* pParams, ScriptParam* pResult)
```

Comment: With that exception message, there's usually an `InnerException` that has all the details. Check out the type, message, and stack trace for the inner exception.

Comment: Your method is marked `async`, yet you don`t `await` anything, hence its redundant. Also, you create a new thread only to invoke the `Dispatcher` and update the UI thread, why? aren't you already in the UI thread inside `update()`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Where is `msg` coming from?

Answer (score 1):

The UI updation part needs to be done on Dispatcher thread if there is another processing going on which may conflict to your thread,So modify your code like this:

```
public string update()
        {
            string[] sMsg = msg.Split(new Char[]{'\n'});

            string[] finalmsg = sMsg[0].Split(new Char[]{':'});

            if ((finalmsg.Length != 8 && sMsg[0] == msg) || sMsg.Length < 2)
            { // not finished reading 
                //Debug.WriteLine("\n\n--skip as the size is : " + finalmsg.Length);
                return null;
            }

            msg = msg.Substring(sMsg[0].Length+2,msg.Length-(sMsg[0].Length+2));
            if (finalmsg.Length >= 8){

                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
                    {
                        string[] fm = finalmsg;
                        RX.Text = finalmsg[0];
                        RY.Text = finalmsg[1];
                        LX.Text = finalmsg[2];
                        LY.Text = finalmsg[3];
                        RF1.Text = finalmsg[4];
                        RF2.Text = finalmsg[5];
                        LF1.Text = finalmsg[6];
                        LF2.Text = finalmsg[7];
                    });                             
            }

            return finalmsg[0];
        }
```

Just make sure modify your code such that UI updation should take place in Dispatcher.No need of putting Dispatcher in other thread.